# How to show password entered when checkbox is clicked?

Tags: angular7

in my form i have one checkbox so when i check the checkbox it should show password entered in password field.i am doing it using angular 7.

```
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Password" class="control-label">Password</label>
  <div>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password" ngModel 
  #pwd="ngModel" placeholder="Password" required  pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(? 
  =.* 
    [A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$">
    <div *ngIf= pwd.invalid>
      <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf= 
     pwd.errors.required>Password Required</small>
      <small class="form-text text-danger" 
      *ngIf=pwd.errors.pattern>Minimum eight characters, at least one 
      uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special 
       character.</small>


  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" 
    [disabled]="pwd.invalid">
  <label class="form-check-label" id="show" for="exampleCheck1">Show 
  Password</label>
</div>
```

By checking the checkbox it should show password entered in the password field.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome on Stackoverflow!

<s>Try to switch between type="password" and type="text" based on checkbox value.</s>

Add #showPassword to your checkbox input, like that :

```
<input #showPassword type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" [disabled]="pwd.invalid">
```

Then on your password field :

```
<input type="showPassword.checked ? 'text' : 'password'" .... />
```

**EDIT (in case you did not solve it yet, and for others) :**

**component.ts**

```js
// show/hide boolean variable
showPassword: boolean;

constructor() {
  // init value in constructor
  this.showPassword = false;
}

// click event, show/hide based on checkbox value
showHidePassword(e) {
    this.showPassword = e.target.checked;
}
```

**component.html**

```html
<input [type]="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'" />

<input type="checkbox" (change)="showHidePassword($event)" > toggle view
```

Comment: @AbhishekSharma I edited my answer to put a valid solution. Hope it helps. Sorry for being so long to answer btw ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I will try wid this solution of urs..If any problem occurs i will contact you..Thanks..